# jQuery: CSS function not firing after animate function

Tags: jquery

Please could someone explain why the following doesnt work. This happens on the same click event but the CSS function is not straight after so I dont want to use the callback on the animate function if possible.

**Note: animation fires but css doesnt.**

```
            container.animate({
                left : (posLeft + slideWidth),
            });


                container.css({
                left : '-'+(itemsLength + startX)+'px',
            });
```

Comment: So you want to set the css left property while it is being animated?

Comment: Explain what you want it to do. You should probably use the callback approach either way.

Comment: Callback or a setTimeout call are the only ways to do this.

Comment: remove the 'hanging' commas. also put the code on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why don't you want to use the callback? Its the best way to do it.

Comment: If anyone can elaborate on Archers comments in an answer then I can give them the answer and help others in similar situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.animate` isn't synchronous,  that is, there's absolutely no guarantee that `.css` is called after `.animate` is (visually) completed. So in your case, after `.animate` is called, `.css` is immediately called, but the `left` position is quickly overriden by `.animate` that internally calls `setInterval`.

According to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), the second argument could be an object that defines the option, and one of them is `complete`

> If supplied, the **complete callback** function is fired once the
>   animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different
>   animations together in sequence. The callback is not sent any
>   arguments, but this is set to the DOM element being animated. If
>   multiple elements are animated, the callback is executed once per
>   matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

```
container.animate({
   left : (posLeft + slideWidth),
}, {
   complete: function() {
      $(this).css({ // as per doc, this is the DOM element being animated
         left : '-'+(itemsLength + startX)+'px',
      }); 
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer SiGanteng, hope this helps others.